# Get first LinkedHashMap key based on value in Java

Tags: java, stream, hashmap, java-stream, linkedhashmap

I use the following `LinkedHashMap` and get the occurences of numbers as `<number, occurences>`.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

The values stored in the map are as in the following:

```
key | value
4   | 2
10  | 2
5   | 1
3   | 1
```

I want to get the first key that has value of 1 (in the example, it is 5). If there is not a key that has value of 1, it returns -1. I use the following approach, but I think it is not a proper way and there may be a better or short way to do this:

```
int key = map.containsValue(1) ?
                map.entrySet().stream()
                   .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1)
                   .map(Map.Entry::getKey).findFirst().get() : -1;
```

So, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by a "better" way? Better in what way?

Comment: @Sweepy Short or simple, or much faster

Comment: I suppose you could skip `map.containsValue()`

Comment: @havriluk But I need to return -1 if there is not any key that has value of 1. Then, what should I do?

Comment: @stack see the first answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking `containsValue` first, use [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) on the optional returned by `findFirst`, which is one fewer iteration through the map.

```
int key = map.entrySet().stream()
               .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1)
               .map(Map.Entry::getKey).findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

`findFirst` would return an empty optional if there is nothing left after the filter. This only happens if there is no value 1 in the map to begin with. `orElse` returns its argument, if the optional is empty, otherwise it returns the wrapped value.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for, thanks a lot amigo voted up. On the other hand, I also used `map.getOrDefault` method for another place like `int value = map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1;` In this part, I want to increase the value of the key by 1 (if the key is not present in the map, it starts from 0 and I add +1). So, is there also a better way for `getOrDefault` in this example?

Comment: @stack You want to get a key from a value, rather a value from a key here, so `getOrDefault` does not help. :(

Comment: Noo, I asked it for `int value = map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1;` part only. In this example I want to check if the key exists and increase its value by 1 (if not exists, set it to 1). So, any suggestion for this part?

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly. But I could not understand how should I replace the last parameter for my example: `int value = map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)` or another usage is `map.merge(key, 1, (a,b) -> a+b);`. Any idea?

Comment: I checked, but cannot convert `int value = map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1;` by using `map.merge` e.g. `int value = map.merge(key, 1, ???? )`. So, what should be the last parameter denoted by "????"

Comment: @stack Oh I think I understand now. You *don't* want to modify the map? Then just keep using `int value = map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1;`. I see nothing that needs to be changed. In any case, what does this have to do with the original question you posted? If you have a different problem, please post another question.

Comment: Ok amigo, marked this reply as answer and opened a new question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361400/how-to-increase-hashmap-value-using-merge-method-in-java