# How to increase HashMap value using merge method in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have the following *list* and use `LinkedHashMap`.

I want to increase the *value* of the *key* by `1` (if the key is **not present** in the map, it starts from `0`, and I add `+1`):

```
int nums[] = new int[]{4, 10, 5, 4, 2, 10};

Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    int key = nums[i];
    int value = map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1;

    // I want to use merge method, but have no idea 
    // what should be the 3 rd parameter denoted by "<??????>"
    int value = map.merge(key, 1, <??????>)

    map.put(key, value);
}
```

However, I want to use `merge()` method, but have no idea what should be the third parameter denoted by "`<??????>`" (*see the code*).

So, how can I use merge method in this scenario?

Comment: Can you explain exactly how `Integer::sum` doesn't work?

Comment: Possibly related: [how to easily sum two hashMap<String,Integer>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33640088)

Comment: @Sweeper Do you mean `int value = map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);` amigo? I tried, but could not understand how it is working in this example. Any clarification pls?

Comment: Ah I think I see where your confusion is. You don't need `int value =` if you just want to update the map. And you don't need `map.put(key, value);`. Just do `map.merge` and that's it.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. So, could you please explain me how `map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);` line works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter of the [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method is a `BiFunction`, i.e. a functional interface accepting two parameters of generic type V (the type of your values) and returning the merge of said values.

Assuming that in your code you're trying to get the frequency of each key, although you wrote "it starts from 0 and I add +1", here is an example of what you were attempting.

In your case, since for each key you're always mapping the value 1 and then incrementing it, you could implement the `BiFunction` merge either by summing the two colliding values, `(v1, v2) -> v1 + v2`, or by adding 1 to the previously mapped value `(v1, v2) -> v1 + 1`.

```
int nums[] = new int[]{4, 10, 5, 4, 2, 10};

Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    map.merge(nums[i], 1, (v1, v2) -> v1 + 1);

    //Alternatively summing the two values
    //map.merge(nums[i], 1, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

However, if your goal was to get the number of key collisions rather than their frequency, then the code above would still work by simply replacing the initial value 1 with 0.

```
int nums[] = new int[]{4, 10, 5, 4, 2, 10};

Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    map.merge(nums[i], 0, (v1, v2) -> v1 + 1);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: @stack Did you run the code? A *key* encountered for the firs time (absent in the map)  will be associated with `1`, not `0`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I think he wants to get the frequency of each key. Probably when he wrote "it starts from 0 and I add +1" was a typo by judging by his code.

Comment: Yeah, I tried and works (I used `map.merge(nums[i], 1, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);` way). Thanks a lot amigos.

Comment: @stack good to know. I've also updated the answer in case you wanted to get either the frequency as posted originally or the number of collisions.

Answer (score 1):

If only increment/decrement is needed on the integer values, a more economic approach (fewer instances of `Integer` created) would be to use a mutable integer class (like `AtomicInteger`) as the value type.

Increment/Decrement would then be trivial:

```java
Map<String, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<>();
// Create a mapping for key "foo" if not exists, then increment
int n = map.computeIfAbsent("foo", (k) -> new AtomicInteger())
    .incrementAndGet(); // or addAndGet() or similar
```

Comment: @user16320675, i noted that "economic" means fewer instances of `Integer` created. If you use `Integer` as a value type, each update/merge will create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

> if the key is **not present** in the map, it starts from `0` and I add `+1`

In order to start count from `zero` you can use method [`compute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)), which expects a *key* and *remappingFunction* that allow to compute a *new value* based on the *key* and *existing value*:

```
int nums[] = new int[]{4, 10, 5, 4, 2, 10};
    
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
for (int num : nums) {
    map.compute(num, (k, v) -> v == null ? 0 : v + 1);
}
    
System.out.println(map);
```

*Output:*

```
{4=1, 10=1, 5=0, 2=0}
```

- keys `4` and `10` - occur twice and therefore will be associated with the value of `1`;
- keys `5` and `2` - will be encountered only once and therefore get mapped to the value of `0` (as it was required for the keys that were encountered for the first time, i.e. **not present** in the map)

---

> However, I want to use `merge()`

With `map.merge(num, 1, Integer::sum);` a key that hasn't been present in the map will be associated with the value of `1` from the beginning. I.e. the *remappingFunction* provided as the third argument will not be executed and a new entry comprised from the offered *key* and *value* would be placed into a map.

And then when such key will be encountered second, third, etc. time the *remappingFunction* will be used to combine the old value and a new value (`1`), i.e. value will be incremented by one.

To achieve the same result as shown above with `merge()`, we can place condition around `merge()`. Inside a condition, we can use `putIfAbsent()` to initialize the entry will `0`. If the given key wasn't present, `putIfAbsent()` will return `null`, otherwise existing value:

```
int nums[] = new int[]{4, 10, 5, 4, 2, 10};
    
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
for (int num : nums) {
    if (map.putIfAbsent(num, 0) != null) {
        map.merge(num, 1, Integer::sum);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
{4=1, 10=1, 5=0, 2=0}
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly. So, could you please explain me how ` map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);` line works?

Comment: @stack The value of one 1 will be placed, if key is absent, otherwise the function will be evaluated

Comment: @stack if you need to start from `0` - `compute()` is the better option